# How to have collection of buttons inside tableview header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uibutton

How to have collection of tag buttons inside tableview header

[image]

which scroll horizontally and with multiple selections.

Comment: You might want to try using a horizontal collectionview. Something like this https://medium.com/@fhalteh/creating-a-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-dynamic-cell-size-f6ce210f7aa9

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:) -> UIView {

    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: <"HeaderView">)
    headerView.tag = section
    return headerView
}
```

Use this UITableViewDelegate method to create a custom view for your header.

Subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView as your custom UIView.
Custom view should have a horizontal scroll view with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to achieve this functionality would be to -

1. Create a ViewContoller class which has a UITableView object inside it. Let's call this class `TableVC` ([Code here](https://github.com/animeshkmar/HorizontalTagsDemoApp/blob/master/HorizontalLayoutGym/TableVC.swift))
2. Create a Header class for this tableView. Let's call it 'TableHeader' ([code here](https://github.com/animeshkmar/HorizontalTagsDemoApp/blob/master/HorizontalLayoutGym/TableHeader.swift))
3. Create a collectionView object inside this tableView header as shown in the code shared in point 2.
4. Create a `CollectionViewCell` class which has a UIButton object as your tag ([code here](https://github.com/animeshkmar/HorizontalTagsDemoApp/blob/master/HorizontalLayoutGym/CollectionViewCell.swift))
5. Finally, create a `TableViewCell` class to do what ever your design suggests. In my example, I've just created a UILabel object in here to show the name of the tag that was tapped/selected ([code here](https://github.com/animeshkmar/HorizontalTagsDemoApp/blob/master/HorizontalLayoutGym/TableViewCell.swift))

Here's a link to a working project I created and hosted on GitHub. Feel free to clone it and play around - https://github.com/animeshkmar/HorizontalTagsDemoApp.git

I build my UI programatically but you can do this very easily with the storyboard as well.

Also, I have passed the `refreshTableVC` function down from `TableVC` to `CollectionViewCell` class as a closure. You can achieve this using delegates and protocols too. I just find closures more straightforward. More ideas about this preference comes from [this insightful article](https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-delegates-in-swift-7ef808a7f16b) by Marin Benčević.